# How do I validate a TkEntry's contents using Ruby/Tk?

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I want to have a TkEntry that only accepts numerical values, but I can't figure out how to do that.
The `:validatecommand` only gets called on once, when the TkEntry is initialized, and I can't figure out how to properly pass an argument in!

Here's an example file that illustrates my problem:

```rb
require 'tk'

# validation method
def isNumerical?
    return false # i plan to actually do something here once i can get a variable in
end

def initWindow
    @root = TkRoot.new { 
        title "Bluebird"
        minsize 400, 300
        setgrid
    }

    entry = TkEntry.new(
        @root,
        :width=>5,
        :textvariable=>TkVariable.new("2241"),
        :validate=>"key",
        :validatecommand=>proc{isNumerical?}
    ).grid(:column=> 0, :row=> 0)
end

initWindow
Tk.mainloop
```

Comment: Please follow this advice from the StackOverflow Help Center: "[Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)." Given your current example code, unfortunately others cannot do so! Please alter your example code, so as to enable us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please follow this advice from the StackOverflow Code of Conduct, "[(M)ake it as easy as possible for others to help you](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)." In part, this means that you should make all of the alterations to your example code which are necessary, for other people, in order to make it reproduce the problem, rather than leaving the considerable work of making those alterations, to those who wish to help you.

Comment: Did you actually try running your example code (by itself) in Ruby? (I'm getting `NameError: uninitialized constant LOGGER`.) If not, then please do so, and continue to fix the problems which arise until your example program entirely works, except for the substance of your question.

Comment: I just did that.

Comment: Please follow this advice from the StackOverflow Help Center: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)" and "[What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)" In part, this states that "[a]ccepting an answer...simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally...[C]lick on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."

Comment: So, if my answer actually solved the particular, exact problem which you described in your question (as opposed to further problems which may arise, as you continue to develop your code), then please click my answer to accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The :validatecommand only gets called on once, when the TkEntry is initialized[.]

Not so!

> I can't figure out how to properly pass an argument in[.]

I minimally tweaked your program, in order to pass an argument to its validation method, and to print the entry string:

```rb
require 'tk'

# validation method
def isNumerical?(s)
    puts s
#   return false # i plan to actually do something here once i can get a variable in
    return true
end

def initWindow
    @root = TkRoot.new { 
        title "Bluebird"
        minsize 400, 300
        setgrid
    }

    entry = TkEntry.new(
        @root,
        :width=>5,
        :textvariable=>TkVariable.new("2241"),
        :validate=>"key",
        :validatecommand=>[proc{|s| isNumerical?(s)}, "%P"]
    ).grid(:column=> 0, :row=> 0)
end

initWindow
Tk.mainloop
```

BTW, I think that you'll find these useful:

1. [Tcl documentation of ttk_entry](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_entry.htm); and
2. [Ruby Tk sample code](http://github.com/ruby/tk/tree/master/sample).